# jQuery function are not working on getting element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to get the click function like this

```
 $('#myTab li a').click(function(e) {}
```

It doesn't work. But if I access the element by class like this

```
 $('.nav-tabs a.overview').click(function(e) {}
```

It works fine.

Similarly when I try to use this

```
 $("#documentmodal").modal('show');
```

it doesn't work. Instead when I write this

```
 $(".documentmodal").modal('show');
```

it works.

I don't know what is the problem with element id, but when I try to access using id in my application functions doesn't work, but they work with the class name.

HTML markup:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-justified" role="tablist" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#overview" class="overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#document" role="tab" class="document" data-toggle="tab">Document</a></li>
    <li><a href="#payment" role="tab" class="payment" data-toggle="tab">Payment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" class="setting" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<div class="modal fade documentmodal"  id="documentmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="downloadLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">...
</div>..
```

I cant put the whole html structure here

Comment: Are you using duplicate IDs? You need to show HTML otherwise everyone will make a guess.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML?

Comment: I think that you need to get clientid

Comment: no there are not duplicate ids.

Comment: wrap your jQuery inside `$(function(){....})`

Comment: either your elements don't have ids or you might have somekind of typo in the ids.

Comment: wrapping inside $(function(){....}) doesn't work

Comment: Or your DOM structure doesn't match `<... id="myTab"><li><a>` etc.  As @Satpal says, without seeing the HTML, all you'll get is guesses.

Comment: My Bad. actually duplicate elements were being generated dynamically with id ,because of multiple ng-view directive in ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is in your HTML, you have class="nav-tabs" but  you dont have the id="myTabs".

Can you share the html?

```
$(function() {
  $('#myTab li a').click(function(e) {  
      $('#documentmodal').show();
      alert('clicked!');
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/bohilukapa/1/edit

Comment: Can you share the complete JS too?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yesiyuxuco/1/edit?html,js,output the html looks fine, i think the problem is in the js

Comment: My Bad. actually duplicate elements were being generated dynamically with id ,because of multiple ng-view directive in ng-show